# Embeded Acrobat Reader in Windows 8 Store Application

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, acrobat

How can I embed Acrobat Rader in aWindows 8 Store Application. There are some tutorials based on C# and there some related question but I could not find any solution. They all suggest adding a COM element and then selecting Acrobat Reader control from toolbox. I have added Acrobat Reader COM element but it gave me error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad to say, but at this time, the only way to read pdf files inside a Windows 8 Store app is to use commercial libraries such as [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this if you want your application to be certified for distribution on the Windows Store.

COM objects can be used in Windows Store Apps, but they must be distributed with your application package, and **they must not use any forbidden API for the Windows Store**. This is must likely not the case for the ActiveX control of Acrobat Reader, since it uses (just to mention one example) the OPENFILENAME dialog, which is not allowed in Windows Store.

**Edit on April 2013:**

[Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT](http://w8pdf.com) (a commercial library) is currently available as [pre-release trial](https://www.amyuni.com/en/resources/trialdownloads/). This library provides a Xaml control for PDF viewing in Xaml-based projects, and it can also be used for PDF-to-HTML5 convertion in WinRT-Javascript projects.  *Disclaimer: I currently work as a developer of the library*